# Open source login based wiki

Tags: wiki

We are looking to setup a open source wiki for a group of users.

But we want it a password protected/ login based.

Any suggestions?

*(admin based , new user can be added and old account can be disabled/ deleted)*

Comment: This is off topic, please post in http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Shouldn't this be in http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

[MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) can do it

Answer (score 1):

Look at [pmWiki](http://www.pmwiki.org/). It allows you to add a script called [AuthUser](http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/PmWiki/AuthUser) which will let you add user controls to the whole site or even just individual pages.

Comment: I really like PmWiki because it's super simple - everything is stored in text files so no need to muck with mysql.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [MindTouch](http://www.mindtouch.com/) for this. It's a little bit of a bear to install, but it's probably the simplest of the open-source solutions I've found from an administrative standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) but this needs to be moved to webmasters.

Comment: anybody can register and edit the page. I want to have admin based wiki where admin sends invitation.